vue-18n, how to translate strings outside of a vue component?
I have a server that can respond to API calls with generalized error codes. Example error code: general.invalid_language. I want to keep the translations of these codes on the frontend side. I'm using vue-i18n in my application. There are many places where APIs are called, and the general pattern for calling these APIs is:
loading = ref(false)
data = ref('')

const doSomething = async() => {
  loading.value = true
  try {
    data.value = await some_api.call()
    loading.value = false
  } catch (e) {
    loading.value = false
    showError(e)
  }
}

The error itself is the error code (string, e.g. general.invalid_language), or an error object that contains the error code, and possibly other arguments. There are many places where APIs are called, and I want to have this general showError(e: any) function that would translate the error code into a message that is human readable.
Example implementation (let's suppose the error is the error code itself):
import { ElMessageBox } from "element-plus";
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

const { t } = useI18n()

export const showError = async (e: any) => {
    ElMessageBox({
        type: 'error',
        message: t('general.error') + "  " + 
                 // this converts the error code to a human-readable message
                 t("" + e),
    })
}

But this does not compile, useI18n() fails with error "must be called at the top of a setup function". I'm sure, there are good reasons for this restriction. But it there a workaround?
I don't see how I could put my showError() function into a component. Even if I could put this code into a component, I'm not sure how I could import and call it. The essential requirement here is to wrap API calls with catch/showError; and API calls can occur anywhere. (Not just in components, but literally anywere.)
All I want is to have a showError() function that could be imported and used from anywhere.

Of course, I could pass the t function as an argument to showError(), but then I would have to import t in the file where the API is called, and that is possibly not inside a component...

Looks like it is not different, import i18n from '../i18n' and then const { t } = i18n.global does work. Closing this as a duplicate.
